# How can I do this with sass and react?

Tags: reactjs, sass

I have a component that render some buttons in the page. 
To style the buttons I am using .scss so the classes looks like this:

```
className={styles.tag}
```

and the corresponding scss is like this:

```
.tagsContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;


    .tag  {
        display: block;
        background-color: #f4f4f4;

        i {
            margin-left: 50px;
            font-size: 1.4em;
        }
    }
```

I was lookin to this codePen that does what I want but is using normal css: [Adding and removing classes](https://codepen.io/JorgeGWD/pen/jYMVXY)

How can I adapt that code to use it with scss nad more exactly with this syntax: {styles.tag}?

Regards
Americo

**THIS IS AN UPDATE:** 
I tested this code:

```
<div  onClick={(e) => { e.stopPropagation(); this.collectTags(tag); }}>
            <p className={`${this.state.addClass == true ? styles.tag : ""}`}
                ># {tag.title} <i className="ms-Icon ms-Icon--CirclePlus"></i></p>
        </div>
```

look closely to the p-tag. this code is changing the style onClick but the problem is that is changing all the p-tags in the compoenent and not only the one that was clicked.

Comment: My best guess is `{styles.tagsContainer.tag}`. I'm not sure it'll pick `.tag` up just by itself (as you could also have a `.tag` inside another CSS class).

Comment: Thanks, I know that pointing {styles.tag} I get the right style but how adapt the linked  sample that uses normal css to scss. that is my question.

Comment: Ah, I get what you mean. I'll write up an answer for this that should be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    addButtonClass: false
  };

  toggleClass = () => {
    this.setState({
      addButtonClass: !this.state.addButtonClass
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { addButtonClass } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button
          className={`button ${addButtonClass ? " button--red" : ""}`}
          onClick={this.toggleClass}
        >Click me </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**style.scss**

```
.button {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: white;
  background-color: green;

  &--red {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the style reference does is return a string className, so you can manipulate it just like you would any other string. Here's a generic example:

```
// this can be any string, even an empty string to start
let testCircleClass = `${cssModule.infoCircle}`;
if(test > 0) {
  coursesCircleClass += ` ${cssModule.hasContent}`;
}
```

So you'd probably need something like:

1. An event handler for the click event.
2. A state to handle if this event has been processed.
3. To then tie the `styles.tag` to this state, once activated.